# Wifi suddenly is very slow Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, internet

I've an important and strange problem.
My wifi sometimes becomes very slow or doesn't work. ( Kbs instead of ~ 20 Mbs). I notice it because the web page obviously doesn't load. When I notice, I disconnect to it and after that reconnect to it and the problem disappears.

It happens two / three times a day.

How can I monitor the situation to identify the problem?

I ask here before open a bug.

info pc :

- always on, when i not use it I put in freeze mode.
- hp
- ubuntu 20.04
- `03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`

Comment: Have you checked the router to which the WiFi is connected?

Comment: @Puspam no, this only happens with the ubuntu pc. My phone and the other doens't have this problem.